# bubble slider onchange value trigger an alert not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using bubble slider, i want to trigger an function if value of an id change its value.

demo: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Range-Slider-Plugin-jQuery-Bubble-Slider/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#item_quantity").on('change', function() {
    alert("Works");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <label class="">How many Email Newsletters would you like? </label>
  <div class="form-group  col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <input class="bubble-slider" name="item_quantity" id="item_quantity" placeholder="0 - 10" type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="1" data-thumb-color="#1C8EC5" data-thumb-scale="0.5" data-track-scale="0.75">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try putting your function instead of `alert("Works");`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `$("#item_quantity").on('change', function() { //do something })` function into a `document.ready` function? Unsure what purpose the initial wrap `$(function() {` serve. Also, your snippet works for me. What seems to be the issue?